# Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1 when trying to import records into a table

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to import some records into a table in my database. The table already has data.

I've checked similar issues here and tried al recommended solution but I'm still getting the error.

Here is a screenshot of my phpmyadmin:

[image]

In my csv file I have removed the header and also replaced semi-colons with commas.

These are my column names:

```
name,last_name,role_id,username,email,street,apartment_etc,city,state,country,zip_code,email_verified_at,password,profile_image,company_name,created_at
```

and here is an example record I'm trying to import:

```
NULL,NULL,3,NULL,s8888888@gmail.com,NULL,NULL,NULL,BU,HU,NULL,2022.03.14 18:57,$2y$10$yyqbgtc1WFpgWz8ofH70ieDu2fdISEnSDvN5d/Y14hMK3osUNUlmC,default-user-avatar.png,NULL,2021.06.03 11:24
```

Maybe the problem is that the table already has records in it?

Comment: Commas Separated With appears to be blank.

Comment: You mean "Columns separated with"? It's not blank.

Comment: Just my montor then - and yes that's what I meant. Please add your full table defintion as text.

Comment: really bad image, still remove the enclsed and escaped, but the biggewst problem is yyou 1have 18 columns and only 15 values in the csv

Comment: @nbk I also tried it by removing the enclosed and escaped. Actually I got 16column with 16values

Comment: And without additional programs, by `LOAD DATA` query (if the data structure in CSV is too irregular, then you can read the entire string into one virtual field, and then parse into separate columns using input preprocessing), do you know how to import? If so, then do. If not, then learn, and then do.